# Manually editing dependency tree in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I've got a large Excel spreadsheet. It includes many data tables that various lookup functions are run on. To make version control easier, I'm currently in the process of pulling these data tables out into separate .csv files, so they can be diffed properly. Unfortunately, they contain a few formulae, which obviously won't work properly when I convert the file to a static .csv.

My current solution is to, wherever a calculation is unavoidable, move the calculation to its own cell in the main workbook and name the cell. Let's call it `ExampleCalc`. Then, in the cell on the data table where the calculation was, I instead enter `ref:ExampleCalc`. Then to do the lookup, I wrote the following UDF:

```
Function RaceLookup(lookupString As Variant, lookupTable As Range, raceID As Range, cleanIt As Boolean) As Variant
    ' Helper function to make the interface formulae neater
    Dim temp As Variant
    Dim temp2 As String
    Dim inpString As Variant
    Dim id As Double

    id = raceID.Value

    If TypeOf lookupString Is Range Then
        inpString = lookupString.Value
    Else
        inpString = lookupString
    End If

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        temp = .Index(lookupTable, id, .Match(inpString, .Index(lookupTable, 1, 0), 0))
        If Left(temp, 4) = "ref:" Then
            temp2 = Right(temp, Len(temp) - 4)
            temp = Range(temp2).Value
        End If

        If cleanIt Then
            temp = .clean(temp)
        End If
    End With

    RaceLookup = temp

End Function
```

This does a standard `INDEX` lookup on the data sheet. If the entry it finds doesn't start with `ref:`, it just returns it. If it does start with `ref:`, it strips the `ref:` and treats whatever's left as a cell name reference. So if the value the `INDEX` returns is `ref:ExampleCalc`, then it will return the contents of the `ExampleCalc` cell.

The problem is that `ExampleCalc` doesn't get added to the dependency tree. That means that if the value of `ExampleCalc` changes, the retrieved value doesn't update. Is there any way to make the function add `ExampleCalc` to the cell's dependency tree? Alternatively, is there a more sensible way to do this?

Comment: Hi Tam, I'm interested about your version control effort. Did you manage to find a working solution? Did your solution include cell formatting? Thanks

Comment: I don't remember, I'm afraid. I haven't worked on that project for quite some time now. Everything is on my GitHub, though, if you felt like hunting it down yourself - the link is on my profile, or you can search for HeroForge Anew.

Comment: Thanks Tam. I'll have a look around.

Answer (score 2):

The solution i have found is to add the line

```
Application.Volatile True   ' this causes excel to know that if the function changes, it should re calculate.  You will still need to click "Calculate Now"
```

into the function.  However, as my code comment indicates, if the only change is in the functional output, you'll have to manually trigger a recalculation.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195441.aspx  for more information.

Comment: As I understand it, making a function volatile means it will recalculate any time anything in the entire workbook changes, which can add substantially to the overhead of the workbook if there's a lot of calculations downstream of the volatile function.